# Difference between UIButton methods that set image

Tags: ios, uibutton

Please tell me what's the difference between two UIButton methods:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

and

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Apple documentation says nothing about it.

Comment: Eventually the background image can be overlayed by a transparent image... but this is just an idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setBackgroundImage` sets the background image of the button. Typically you use this in conjunction with a button of type "Custom" to use the background image as a nice shape and background for the button (say an image representing a rectangle with rounded corners and filled with a nice gradient)

`setImage` adds an image/icon next to the title of the button, (all of which, image and title, are overlayed over the background image, of course, that's why it's called "background" after all). If you set some title to you button too, the image will be drawn next to the title and its position will depend on the title length (and also on the titleContentInsets / imageContentInsets properties to adjust this position)

Just try it in Interface Builder (set an image for both, play around by setting a title, etc) you will understand it easier.